# Why is a T-SQL variable comparison slower than GETDATE() function-based comparison?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a T-SQL statement that I am running against a table with many rows.  I am seeing some strange behavior.  Comparing a DateTime column against a precalculated value is slower than comparing each row against a calculation based on the GETDATE() function.

The following SQL takes 8 secs:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
DECLARE @TimeZoneOffset int = -(DATEPART("HH", GETUTCDATE() - GETDATE()))
DECLARE @LowerTime DATETIME = DATEADD("HH", ABS(@TimeZoneOffset), CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101) + ' 17:00:00')
SELECT TOP 200 Id, EventDate, Message 
FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate > @LowerTime
GO
```

This alternate strangely returns instantly:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
GO
SELECT TOP 200 Id, EventDate, Message 
FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE EventDate > GETDATE()-1
GO
```

Why is the second query so much faster?

EDITED: I updated the SQL to accurately reflect other settings I am using

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans? # of records returned?

Comment: Is there an index on the EventDate column? Did you look at the query plans of the two queries?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference here. I can't see any reason why it should either.  GETDATE is only evaluated once per query so once the query has started it behaves just the same as @LowerTime.  In your example GETDATE AND @LowerTime are not the same value.  Do they both return the same number of rows?

Comment: What is the type of the `EventDate` column?

Comment: There is no index on EventDate. I can't compare results because the table is continually growing. I just select the top 200 rows.  The execution plans seem identical except of course the getdate comparison which looks kinda like this EventDate > getdate()-'1900-01-02 00:00:00.000' vs. EventDate > @LowerTime.

Comment: @Jon-Seigel The EventDate column is a DateTime non-null

Comment: It shouldn't take 8 seconds longer but you should know that converting to varchar does take longer than using date math such as DateAdd and DateDiff.

Comment: If the execution plan would be different, the reason would be that GETDATE()-1 can be used with the statistics, while bind parameters can't. However, you mentioned that the plans SEEM to be identical, so that doesn't make sens in this context, unfortunately. Do the row count estimates vary in the execution plans? That is a typical indication for the mentioned problem.

Comment: @ErikE Agreed. However, including the variable declarations with the faster code does not slow it in any perceptable way.  For the slower code, it almost seems like SQL Server is evaluating the variable assignment on every record comparison.

Comment: When you run a trace, are there the same number of reads?

Comment: @Markus-Winand I compared the XML of the execution plans and the only significant difference I could find was with the EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost value .14 vs. .43.  The estimated record counts were the same because the top 200 rows were requested.  The table has over 3 million records and is under load.  @ErikE I don't have access to trace.

Comment: TOP with no ORDER BY isn't a correct query, hence is not a correct test

Comment: @gbn I removed the order by to see if that affected performance. Whether in or out the order by did not change the difference between using the parameter and using the getdate calculation.

Comment: Well, now that peak volume has passed, both queries are now comparable.  I guess it may have had something to do with the high volume of inserts during the period when I was running the queries. Strange.  Not sure what I should do with this question.

Comment: `-(DATEPART("HH", GETUTCDATE() - GETDATE()))` = `DATEDIFF("HH", GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After doing a lot of reading and researching, I've discovered the issue here is parameter sniffing. Sql Server attempts to determine how best to use indexes based on the where clause, but in this case it isnt doing a very good job.

See the examples below :

Slow version:

```
declare @dNow DateTime  
Select @dNow=GetDate()  
Select *  
From response_master_Incident rmi  
Where rmi.response_date between DateAdd(hh,-2,@dNow) AND @dNow
```

Fast version:

```
Select *  
From response_master_Incident rmi  
Where rmi.response_date between DateAdd(hh,-2,GetDate()) AND GetDate()
```

The "Fast" version runs around 10x faster than the slow version. The Response_Date field is indexed and is a DateTime type.

The solution is to tell Sql Server how best to optimise the query. Modifying the example as follows to include the OPTIMIZE option resulted in it using the same execution plan as the "Fast Version". The OPTMIZE option here explicitly tells sql server to treat the local @dNow variable as a date (as if declaring it as DateTime wasnt enough :s )

Care should be taken when doing this however because in more complicated WHERE clauses you could end up making the query perform worse than Sql Server's own optimisations.

```
declare @dNow DateTime

SET @dNow=GetDate()

Select ID, response_date, call_back_phone 
from response_master_Incident rmi
where rmi.response_date between DateAdd(hh,-2,@dNow) AND @dNow

-- The optimizer does not know too much about the variable so assumes to should perform a clusterd index scann (on the clustered index ID) - this is slow

-- This hint tells the optimzer that the variable is indeed a datetime in this format (why it does not know that already who knows)
OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR (@dNow = '99991231'));
```

Comment: +1 this is very interesting, any idea what all this means for the execution plans? Also, does it mean the getdate version is calculating an execution plan each time

Answer (score 0):

The execution plans must be different, because SQL Server does not evaluate the value of the variable when creating the execution plan in execution time. So, it uses average statistics from all the different dates that can be stored in the table.

On the other hand, the function getdate is evaluated in execution time, so the execution plan is created using statistics for that specific date, which of course, are more realistic that the previous ones.

If you create a stored procedure with `@LowerTime` as a parameter, you will get better results.

Comment: You are correct that I was not running this code in a stored procedure but rather interactively in SSMS.  This sounds feasible to me.